# Sentence correction

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

Buying and sending medicine over to them are good ways to them .

What I mean is that buying and sending medicine over to them is better than other methods of getting medicine to them.

Comment: Do you think it's okay. If not, what part do you think is problematic? Why do you think that?

Comment: I have a feeling that "good ways to them" can be replaced with something better. But if it's grammatically correct than I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 2):

> Buying and sending medicine over to them are good ways to them

You need something before *to them*, so you might use an infinitive verb and write *to get it to them*.

Also, *buying and sending medicine over to them* would be considered one thing, and so you would use the singular verb *is* and the singular noun *way*.

Finally, if you think *buying and sending medicine over to them* is better than all other methods, you should use the adjective *best* rather than *good*.

The final sentence might look like this:

> Buying and sending medicine over to them is the best way to get it to them.

Answer (score 2):

> Buying and sending medicine over to them are good ways to them .

I think it's understandable, but inelegant. I agree with Graham Nicol you need to use "best", not "good", but I would put it first for emphasis:

> **The best way to deliver the medicine is to buy it and send it over.**

This emphasizes your idea that "buying and sending medicine over to them is better than other methods of getting medicine to them".

Comment: Very  nice.  Swapping the subject and complement not only emphasizes the important idea (the best way to deliver medicine), but it gets rid of the awkward placement of *over.*